# Nested Aggregate-Initialization Rule

Tags: c++, struct, nested, record, braced-init-list

Given following code:

```cpp
struct B {int i[2];};
struct A {B b[2];};
int main() {
    A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}; //too many initializers for ‘A’
    A{{0, 0}, B{0, 0}}; //too many initializers for ‘A’
    A{B{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
    A{B{0, 0}, B{0, 0}};
}
```

Why would the first two not compile? I think all four lines should mean the same thing since they're all one-to-one mapping?

(The test is compiled using g++ 13.2.0 -std=c++20.)

Comment: _"I also tried ChatGPT, and it thinks I'm right after arguing with it"_ tells you how useless it is. It's also the reason why pasting stuff into ChatGPT doesn't constitute research, it can at most be a starting point.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: *"There must be some kind of rule.."*  Yes, there are. C++ is a very complex language, especially the initialization rules in C++. There are many rules regarding the same in the standard. You have to look at each individual case one by one instead of trying to understand all the cases at once.

Comment: @user12002570 yes I did read the aggregate initialization document, it does talk about `Brace elision` which explains why the initializer list can be "flattened", but that doesn't explain why some of them won't compile I think.

Comment: "Why would some of them unexpectedly compile or not compile?" this completely dpends on your expectations which you didnt tell us. Please reduce the code to the minimum needed to show us the cases where you expectations differ from what happens

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis What I mean is that since your question has so many cases, it is hard and too broad to explain/cover all the case. You can ask about any one particular case that will make the question more concise. Then ask a separate new question about other case. The more broader your question is the less likely that people can answer it.

Comment: "I also tried ChatGPT, and it thinks I'm right after arguing with it..." You don't have to mention that. It is irrelevant. If ChatGPT was any good you wouldnt need to ask this question here. Mentioning ChatGPT adds unnecessary fluff and invites useless comments like this one :P

Comment: Can you focus on one of those lines? [Here's the relevant part of the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#16). Can you explain, for one of the failing lines, how you think it should be valid according to the standard?

Comment: @user12002570 thanks for the advice! edited accordingly

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis Now it makes more sense. Though I would still recommend just focussing on one particular line/statement and remove all the others from the code snippet. Just have one statement in the code snippet that you think is not clear at all and should be applicable to other cases as well. Then, I(and others I presume) can answer that as then we don't have to worry about other cases. And If that answer still doesn't explain other cases, you can always ask a new separate question.

Comment: `A{{1, 2, 3, 4}}` is equivalent to `A{1, 2, 3, 4}`, as `A{{1}}` to `A{1, 0, 0, 0}` (completing partial initialization list). Then `A{ {1,2}, {3, 4}}` is equivalent to `A{1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4}` which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, I don't think `A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` has any ambiguity?

Let us look at [`[dcl.init.aggr]/16`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#16):

> Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows.
> If the initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the elements of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more initializer-clauses than elements.
> If, however, the initializer-list for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the elements of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to initialize the next element of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is an element.

The parsing seems to go as follows:

```
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
// ^ Entering `A`
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
//  ^ Entering `b`
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
//   ^ Entering `b[0]`, the opening brace is omitted.
//   ^ Initializing `b[0].i[0]`
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
//      ^ Initializing `b[0].i[1]`
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
//       ^ Exiting `b[0]`
//       ^ Exiting `b`
  A{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
//          ^ `A` has no more fields, expected `}`
```

Comment: I see, so essentially it's initializing `B b[2],void nothing` with `{0,0},{0,0}` and found a problem. If I cast the first element to B manually, then it can't match `B[]` against `B`, so it have to initialize `B b[2]` with the whole `B{0,0},{0,0}`, and everything becomes fine? I thought it would work more or less like overload, where second priority possibility would be tried if first one doesn't work

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis *"then it can't match `B[]` against `B`, so it have to initialize..."* Yeah, seems so. It's not obvious to me how the brace elision rules could be improved without potentially having to bruteforce a bunch of different ways of splitting initializers between fields.